# Find infimum and supremum of the function $f$ defined by the formula $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ on the set $A$

Tags: compactness, supremum-and-infimum, lagrange-multiplier

> Let $A = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : 5x^2 + 5y^2 - z^2 = 0, x + 2y +3z = 20\}$. Find infimum and supremum of the function $f$
> defined by the formula $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ on the set $A$.

Using Lagrange multipliers I found critical points $(1,2,5)$, $(-2, -4, 10)$. However, I don't know how to check whether these are infimum and supremum of the function or just local extremes. It would be helpful if the set $A$ was compact - then the found extremes must be the infimum and supremum of the $f$ function, but I have no idea how to check the compactness of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersecting a *conical surface* with a *plane surface* of Cartesian equations:

$$
x^2 + y^2 = k^2z^2,
\quad \quad \quad
a\,x + b\,y + c\,z + d = 0
$$

after calculating the discriminant:

$$
\Delta := c^2-(a^2+b^2)k^2
$$

- if $d = 0$ we can find *three degenerate cases*:

  - if $\Delta<0$ then they're *two straight lines*;
  - if $\Delta=0$ then it's *a straight line*;
  - if $\Delta>0$ then it's *a point*;
- if $d \ne 0$ we can find *three non-degenerate cases*:

  - if $\Delta<0$ then they're *two branches of hyperbola*;
  - if $\Delta=0$ then it's *a parabola*;
  - if $\Delta>0$ then it's *an ellipse*.

---

In the present case:

$$
x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{5}z^2,
\quad \quad \quad
x + 2\,y + 3\,z - 20 = 0
$$

then:

$$
d = -20 \ne 0,
\quad \quad \quad
\Delta = 3^2-\left(1^2+2^2\right)\frac{1}{5} = 8 > 0
$$

so it's *an ellipse*.

Therefore, since $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a continuous function on a closed and bounded set, there it admits a *global minimum* $f(1,2,5)=30$ and a *global maximum* $f(-2,-4,10)=120$.

---

If we were also interested in a *parametrization of this ellipse*, from the plane equation:

$$
z = \frac{20-x-2\,y}{3}
$$

which substituted into the cone equation leads to:

$$
44\,x^2  - 4\,x\,y + 41\,y^2 + 40\,x + 80\,y - 400 = 0
$$

which through a study of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of this conic leads to:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ -1 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\cos\theta \\ \sqrt{10}\,\sin\theta \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

i.e.

$$
\begin{cases} x = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2}\,\cos\theta + 2\sqrt{2}\,\sin\theta \\ y = -1 -3\cos\theta - \sqrt{2}\,\sin\theta \\ z = \frac{15}{2} + \frac{5}{2}\,\cos\theta \\ \end{cases} \quad \quad \text{with} \; \theta \in [0,2\pi).
$$

Of course, for the purposes of this exercise, it isn't strictly necessary.